Please help identify this font with seemingly unique lowercase O's
I require some assistance in trying to identify a font utilised some years ago (circa 2008-2009) on the name of a boat my father had. He has since had several boats but always liked the font utilised on this particular one (and wants to use it on his current one).
Unfortunately the original sign writer who arranged the previous name badge for him passed away some years back, and I have minimal letters to work with due to vessels short name of "Hobo".
I have spent literal hours on identifont.com, WhatIsFont and other sites that proclaim their capability to identify the font from images to no avail.
The lower case o's in this font appear to be unique and I'm hoping them, the lowercase b or the capital H may stand out to someone who has used it before and can name it for me.
A sample of the text is below, an image I had of the vessel which I then ran through pixlr and layered out to get the best clarity I could for uploading to identification sites with no luck.

Any help anyone can provide would be very much appreciated.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The image you supplied is really too small and low resolution to ID easily, but what I notice is that both letter Os are actually different. This would suggest to me that the text is not an actual font, but more likely the lettering was done by hand.  Not everything is a font.

Also worthwhile noting that there are literally tens of thousands of handwriting-style fonts, and font ID sites generally don't work well with these kind of fonts anyway. To find something similar, you would probably have to scroll through thousands of examples to find what you want, or find something close.  Sites such as dafont for example have around 17000 hand writing fonts. It would be like looking for a needle in a haystack.

The lettering was definitely a font on a computer according to the fellas son who did it, he just can't remember which one.  The O's will actually be the same, its just how the magic wand in pixlr picked them up when I highlighted them as a section in the original image.
